# How to run batch file with parameter from DBMS_SCHEDULER chain job

Tags: batch-file, plsql, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

**Case:** 
I have windows batch file `start.bat` which do some operations using `extr_mode` parameter passed from the outside:

```
rem settings
  set extr_mode=%1

rem the rest of the script
```

When I'm calling it from `cmd` using i.e.: `start.bat DAILY` it works fine and parameter is passed.

Now I'm trying to call this batch file under `DBMS_SCHEDULER` chain job's program:

```
begin
  sys.dbms_scheduler.create_program(program_name        => 'OUT_BAT',
                                    program_type        => 'EXECUTABLE',
                                    program_action      => 'C:\Job\start.bat DAILY',
                                    number_of_arguments => 0,
                                    enabled             => true,
                                    comments            => 'Out batch file');
end;
/
```

this program without parameter (`program_action => 'C:\Job\start.bat'`) runs ok, but when I'm adding parameter job is failing. 
 
I mean, I'm checking `dba_scheduler_job_run_details` and for this step `STATUS = SUCCEEDED`, but in `ADDITIONAL_INFO` there is:

```
CHAIN_LOG_ID="490364", STEP_NAME="OUT", STANDARD_ERROR="The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified."
```

I didn't find any specific answer for my question, so is it possible to run batch file with parameter from `DBMS_SCHEDULER` chain job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - thanks for tip @Magoo,

I needed to create `program` first:

```
sys.dbms_scheduler.create_program(program_name          => 'OUT_BAT',
                                    program_type        => 'EXECUTABLE',
                                    program_action      => 'C:\OUT_start.bat',
                                    number_of_arguments => 1,
                                    enabled             => false,
                                    comments            => 'Out batch file');
```

then define `program argument` and enable program:

```
sys.dbms_scheduler.define_program_argument(program_name          => 'OUT_BAT',
                                             argument_position   => 1,
                                             argument_name       => 'DAILY',
                                             argument_type       => 'varchar2',
                                             default_value       => 'DAILY');

sys.dbms_scheduler.enable(name => 'OUT_BAT');
```

then of course the rest elements of dbms_scheduler job.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I've no idea about dbms-scheduler.

Naturally, batch can provide a solution, which may or may not be suitable.

Create a new batch called `startDAILY.bat` containing simply this:

C:\Job\start.bat DAILY

and change your setting

```
program_action      => 'C:\Job\startDAILY.bat'
```

I'm suspicious about your code line stating

> number_of_arguments => 0,

I'd suspect that you may be able to change this to say, `number_of_arguments => 1,`

and then well - perhaps the `dbms-scheduler` manual may give a hint about how to supply `DAILY` as the first argument so that you can use your original code.

Oh BTW - using `start` as a batch name is not a good idea as `START` is a batch keyword.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Magoo, but the reason I want to use parameter here is not to creating other batch files. I wanted one batch file with parameter passed by dbms_scheduler job.